# Bounded fourth moment implies bounded lower moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the moment method, let $X$ be an absolutely integrable real scalar random variable, and assume a finite fourth moment ${{\bf E} |X|^4 < \infty}$, it is stated that all lower moments such as ${{\bf E} |X|^2}$ are thus finite by the Hölder or Jensen inequalities. I can see that by the Hölder inequality with $p=q=2$, we have ${\bf E}|X|^2 = {\bf E}|X|^2 \cdot 1 \leq ({\bf E}|X|^4)^{1/2} < \infty$, but I don't see how can this follow from Jensen's inequality as well, since if we want to use the convex function $f: {\bf R} \to {\bf R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ to conclude $({\bf E}|X|^2)^2 \leq {\bf E}|X|^4 < \infty$ directly, we'll need the condition that $|X|^2$ is absolutely integrable as a priori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can truncate the variables. For $M>0$, define $$X_M = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} X & : |X|\leqslant M \\ 0 & : X\neq 0.\end{array}\right.$$

Then $\lim_M X_M=X$ almost surely. By the monotone convergence theorem, $$\lim_M \mathbb{E}|X_M|^4=\mathbb{E}|X|^4.$$ Apply Jensen's inequality to each $X_M$, which are all bounded and so have all moments finite, to deduce that $$[\mathbb{E}|X_M|^2]^2\leqslant \mathbb{E}|X_M|^4\leqslant \mathbb{E}|X|^4$$ for all $M$.

Again, by the monotone convergence theorem (and continuity of the square function), $$[\mathbb{E}|X|^2]^2 = \lim_M [\mathbb{E}|X_M|^2]^2\leqslant \mathbb{E}|X|^4.$$

The monotone convergence theorem is valid even without the assumption that $\mathbb{E}|X|^2<\infty$, because if $\mathbb{E}|X|^2=\infty$, then $$\lim_M \mathbb{E}|X_M|^2=\infty.$$

A similar trick will work for any other powers $0<p<q<\infty$. We apply Jensen's inequality with the convex function $f(x)=x^{q/p}$.

Comment: Thanks, the original text gives a sense of a simple one-line argument, so I was trying to do it by Jensen's inequality alone. If $Y_n := \min(|X|^2, n)$, then by the MCT (or the horizontal truncation property), combined with Jensen's inequality, the result follows indeed.

Comment: We could "cheat" and make this a one-line argument by noting that if $Y$ is non-negative and $\varphi:[0,\infty]\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex (and therefore continuous) and non-decreasing, then Jensen's inequality applies whenever $\mathbb{E}\varphi(Y)<\infty$ and implies that $\varphi(\mathbb{E}X)<\infty$. Here I'm assuming that $\mathbb{P}(Y=\infty)=0$. Then $Y_M\nearrow Y$ almost surely and $\varphi(Y_M)\nearrow \varphi(Y)$ almost surely (because $\varphi$ is non-decreasing). Apply Jensen to $Y_M$ and MCT.

Comment: This doesn't reduce the work. But it moves it over to be an easy corollary of Jensen's inequality, and then when we come to this problem, we get it in one line through the corollary.